# Posição de texto em gráfico usando o ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Preciso ajustar a posição de um texto no gráfico de barras para que ele fique acima da barra. Abaixo o código utilizado

```
base.total %>%
  group_by(SEXO, REGIME.JURIDICO.FINAL)%>%
  count() %>%
  ggplot(., aes(x=reorder(SEXO, -n), y=n, fill = REGIME.JURIDICO.FINAL)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width = 0.2, position = "dodge") +
  labs(title = "Gráfico 11: Quantidade de Inativos Civis e Militares",
       subtitle = "Fonte: Base de Dados SIGRH", x = "Sexo", y="Quantidade") + 
  theme(axis.line.x = element_line(size = .5, colour = "black"),
        axis.line.y = element_line(size = .5, colour = "black"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "black", size = 7),
        axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "black", size = 7),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        legend.title = element_blank()) +  
  geom_text(aes(label = n), size = 3.0, position = position_dodge(width = 0.2))
```

[image: Resultado do código acima]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Achei uma sugestão no Stack Overflow em inglês (nesse [tópico](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39032791/adjusting-location-of-text-with-ggplot-and-plotly)). Adaptando para o seu exemplo, ficaria assim

```
geom_text(aes(label=n, y = n+0.01), size = 3.0, position = position_dodge(width = 0.2))
```

Comment: Acrescentei o 

`geom_text(aes(label = n, y = n+1), size = 3.0, position = position_dodge(width = 0.2))`

E nada aconteceu

Comment: tenta adicionar um valor mais alto, por causa da escala do eixo `y`

Comment: Consegui resolver fiz o `geom_text(aes(label = n, y = n+3000), size = 3.0, position = position_dodge(width = 0.2))` para resolver o problema.